# Intersect between assets that were Uploaded from Shapefile to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection, error

I'm new to Google Engine, I have two shapefiles, one is named Deforestation with almost 600,000 polygons inside of the shapefile, and the second one is named Aliso which is a geometry that only is one polygon. I tried to intersect Deforestation with Aliso using the next function:

Var Areaintersect = Deforestation.intersection(Aliso);

[image]

But when I tried to do the process I got a error message: Line 2: Deforestacion_Corregida.intersection is not a function

How could I solve this error message and get the intersection between this two assets

You can see the project in the next link
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d4078a337b16f7c551d8e22ff937ca94

Comment: It's hard to tell without having access to the files themselves, but it looks like you may have to do an explicit cast i.e. ee.FeatureCollection(Aliso) or ee.Geometry(Aliso) or ee.Feature(Aliso) depending on your file. You may also need to calculate the geometry using .geometry() before intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of those geometries is the null set.  Here's how to find out ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/32f42420c1c0b3570de12b13a65ce9dd)):

```
Map.addLayer(Aliso, {color: 'red'})
Map.addLayer(Deforestacion)
var filtered = Deforestacion.filterBounds(Aliso)
print(filtered.size()) // 0
```

In general, don't call `.geometry()` on a very big collection.  It will try to load all of the geometries into memory at once.  Instead, use a `filterBounds()` or a [spatial join](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_spatial) to find all the features in one collection that intersect those in another.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for that information. May I ask, all of this is made so I am able to download the properties (Anio, Area, Shape_Area, Shape_Leng) of a buffer of 50000 meters that is located in FeatureCollection>features: List (608 elements)>properties: Object (4 properties). Like in this link https://code.earthengine.google.com/9711d956cdb831a5d2af8a397ebd506d. Would you mind telling me how can I export that table as a CSV with the 608 polygons that are inside? Getting as result Anio and Area

Comment: You would `Export` the table.  Here are some examples to get you started: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#to-drive_1.